# Can you import included and DLC tracks from Just Dance 2 into Just Dance 3?

Tags: just-dance-3, just-dance-2

My wife has been enjoying *Just Dance 2* on the Wii since I gave it to her last Christmas and has actually bought a number of additional tracks — enough that I had to buy her a big SD card just for the game. I'm thinking about getting the newest version for her, but I'm curious if she will be able to import the included and DLC tracks from *Just Dance 2* into *Just Dance 3*.

(The game's website is horrid; I've spent quite a bit of time over the last several days searching various official sources of information looking for an answer to no avail, hoping someone that actually owns the title will know.)

Comment: Good question +1. In addition it would be interesting if you can import the songs from Just Dance 1/2 to the Kinect Just Dance 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is NO. There appears to be ZERO connection between the two games. Different DLC content in their stores too.